# MySQL function is not running

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to write the following Query:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `sugaruser`@`%` 
FUNCTION `f_accounts_opps`(`account`    varchar(240))
    RETURNS int(11)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE thetotal int;
        SELECT COUNT(id) 
        INTO thetotal FROM accounts_opportunities 
        WHERE account_id = account;
    RETURN thetotal;
END;
```

The account id is from SugarCRM, so it is likely to be something like:

`78e10d40-d476-4dd7-8031-54b38f5b9bca`

I keep getting an SQL error when I try it out.

I have tried putting accounts in single and double commas.

Comment: Please add error you are getting in your question.

Comment: "Procedure execution failed
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-d476-4dd7-8031-54b38f5b9bca)' at line 1"

Comment: The parameter I am passing in is 78e10d40-d476-4dd7-8031-54b38f5b9bca

Comment: are you passing the value as `select f_accounts_opps('78e10d40-d476-4dd7-8031-54b38f5b9bca')`

Comment: I forgot the ' on the incoming parameter.  What an idiot I am. Won't do that again!